# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to rails and I can't figure out how to fix this bug.
So here are my models:

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { email.downcase! }
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :events, through: :tickets


    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255},
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }


end
```

Event:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :users, through: :tickets

    validates :event_title, presence: true
    validates :event_place, presence: true
    validates :event_description, presence: true
    validates :event_date, presence: true
    validates_numericality_of :event_number_tickets, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, greater_than: 0
end
```

Ticket:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I have a test file for tickets which is

```
require 'test_helper'

class TicketTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(first_name: "Example", last_name: "User")

    @event = Event.new(event_title: "Example Event",
                       event_place: "123 Example Ave.", 
                       event_description: "Our example event for children to get introduced to technology",
                       event_date: DateTime.now,
                       event_number_tickets: 30)
    @ticket = Ticket.new(event: @event, ticket_type: "regular", number_of_children: 1)
    @user.tickets << @ticket
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.tickets.valid?     
  end

end
```

Whenever I run this test I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid?' for #<Ticket::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fae767617c8>
    test/models/ticket_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:TicketTest>'
```

Do I have to create a custom valid method for this particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a `valid?` method for an ActiveRecord collection. If you're trying to test that the last Ticket you created is valid, you can do something like `assert @ticket.valid?`.

I think you might be doing a bit too much work in your setup method. You could try to just setup your User and Event model in the setup, and break the rest of what you described into different test blocks.

Comment: First of all, Thanks! Secondly, I just want to run a test to ensure that I can create an event and associate it with a user.Then, I want to create a ticket and associate it with an event. Then for a particular user, I want to be able to view their events and the tickets for said event

Comment: Cool. I think you're probably doing too much work in the setup method. I'd create a User and an Event in your setup method, and then break out each of what you just described into test blocks. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Got it, no need for an eample. Thanks again